# Is it easier to take the domain from WIX and host the domain under AWS? Or is there another way to do this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

Im trying to host a domain purchased through WIX on AWS. The site is ready to go and waiting in the bucket to be hosted under the domain my client bought through WIX. Just wondering if anyone knew how to take it from WIX and host it on AWS. Ive been looking and only found something that takes the CNAMEs made when you create a hosting zone on AWS and you can add them to google CNAMES (it was a tutorial for taking a google domain and routing to AWS) but since the CNAME section on WIX is greyed out I cant go that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the NS records on Route 53, Go to Wix, Go to the [CNAME Records](https://support.wix.com/en/article/connecting-a-wix-domain-to-an-external-site), and have the CNAME point to the NS on Route 53.

Alternatively, you could [transfer your domain](https://support.wix.com/en/article/transferring-your-wix-domain-away-from-wix-2477749) to AWS, and in Route 53, create a new record set by pressing `create record set`, set type to `NS`, set the name to `www.[yourdomain].com`, and add the wix NS in `Value`.

The first approach with changing the CNAMES in wix should be easier.

Comment: would this method enable me to have a subdomain in aws (eg api.yourdomain.com) with an SSL certificate, while the wix site still hosts the site I made on wix (if I take option 2 from your answer @jordan-daniels)?