# SSL issue when redirecting wix domain to amazon domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I would like to redirect from wix domain to my amazon domain. But when I check NS on Route 53 I see following data:

```
ns-.awsdns-.org. 
ns-*.awsdns-.net. 
ns-****.awsdns-.co.uk.
ns-*.awsdns-**.com.
```

Which one I should put in CNAME of wix or how I put it to CNAME?

I followed the post [Is it easier to take the domain from WIX and host the domain under AWS? Or is there another way to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889801/is-it-easier-to-take-the-domain-from-wix-and-host-the-domain-under-aws-or-is-th/56932576#56932576)

Comment: I am not familiar with Wix but what you need to do in general is to change NS records at your registrar to AWS ones.

Answer (score 1):

Login into AWS console and goto Route 53. You will see the NS entry. In NS entry there will be multiple record sets like,

```
ns1.amazon.com 
ns2.amazon.org 
ns3.amazon.net 
ns4.amazon.co.uk
```

Copy those and paste in the WIX. And make sure there should be no dot in the end of NS record.

Comment: Thanks but when I copied all NS and put to CNAME. The error said "Invalid domain name"

I put like below:
ns-****.awsdns-**.org ns-***.awsdns-**.net ns-****.awsdns-*0.co.uk ns-***.awsdns-**.com

Comment: Instead of creating CNAME in WIX. Change the name servers in WIX. And for each value create a new name server. So there will be four NameServer records. That is how I point my GoDaddy domain to Route53.